# How to get selected items from listbox from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm using `ListBox` to display some value, it works properly but when I am trying to get the selected item from the list box it shows an error null reference error.

Below is my code that I have written to get values from ListBox:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To lsttasks.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    userTaskDtlSrNo = Val(lsttasks.SelectedItems(i).ToString())
    If userTaskDtlSrNos <> "" Then userTaskDtlSrNos &= ","
    userTaskDtlSrNos &= userTaskDtlSrNo
 Next
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: what does `SelectionMode` property is set to?

Comment: Selectionmode is set to MultiSimple

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `Val()` function there

Don't forget to declare `Dim userTaskDtlSrNo as String`

Use: `userTaskDtlSrNo = lsttasks.SelectedItems(i).ToString()`

Comment: this error get:-Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.

Comment: how's `userTaskDtlSrNo` is declared?

Comment: dim userTaskDtlSrNo  as integer

Comment: That's your problem, I reflected it in the answer

Comment: @bhu if that solved your problem, please accept the answer (press the V) :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe your assigning a string to a integer, 
declare userTaskDtlSrNo as String, then use

```
userTaskDtlSrNo = Val(lsttasks.SelectedItems(i).ToString())
```

if you need to change userTaskDtlSNo to an integer after then just use

```
Dim intUserTask As Integer
Integer.TryParse(userTaskDtlSrNo, intUserTask)
```

to assign a new variable with same value as an integer, i dont know the rest of your code but i see no reason why this would not solve your problem.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can be way easier than it looks.

If you want to delete an object that is selected:

```
'let recips be the listbox name
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Recips.Items.Remove(Recips.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

If you want to get the selected item (like for setting it to a string):

```
'let pie be a string variable, and recips to be the listbox again respectively
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
pie = Recips.selectedItem
End Sub
```

I hope this was enough for you, I'm not sure if I covered on enough information. Please comment so, if I forgot. Accept this answer if this helped.